# How to add logging information to perl legacy code

Tags: perl

I have a medium to large size system built in perl, that has been developed during the last 15 years and is built of many scripts and pm files, 
and in order to improve the system i need more data, the easiest way as i see it to get this data is to have every function in the code to print out the start and end time to some log so it will be possible the understand what is taking the most time.
however this is an old system and some parts are less maintainable than others and on top of it i need it to be running which means in order to get real data i need it to print this out from production.
what i want to do is to override in some way the function declration to wrap each function start in a line like
NAME start STARTTIME PARAMS
and when it leaves the function 
NAME ended STARTTIME PARAMS

does anybody can point me to the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [`Devel::NYTProf`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-5.00/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm).  It can profile the amount of time that all of your subs are taking (and do a lot more).  It doesn't involve a lot of messy code modification; instead you just run your script with it:

```
perl -d:NYTProf your_script.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers are spot on (I especially recommend [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel::NYTProf)). However, a more general technique you could apply in general to gather data about your subroutines' behaviour is fiddling with the symbol table, "appending" (or prepending) code to the actual sub's code.

A couple of pointers:

- [In Perl, can I call a method before executing every function in a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663723/203856) (this answer shows a code example you could adapt to your particular situation)
- [Hook::LexWrap](https://metacpan.org/module/Hook::LexWrap) is a module that lets you augment subroutine behaviour in several ways, without touching the original code

HTH

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need to use a profiler

http://www.perl.org/about/whitepapers/perl-profiling.html

Answer (score 0):

Perl profilers usually have a huge impact on the program performance, so using them in production may not be a great idea.

You can try [Devel::ContinuousProfiler](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aContinuousProfiler) that claims to have very low impact (I myself have never used it, just discovered it this morning!)